# textarea, textbox not accepting special characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

I have textboxs and textarea in my asp.net form with their individual max lengths set.
The problem is when I enter  the following text in codes `"<some text>"` it doesn't get saved in the database whose column's datatype is `varchar(300)`

Whereas, in the same input fields, if i enter `< fdgdfg >`, it gets saved.

Please get me some solution for the above mentioned problem. On debugging I get an error message as follows

> "String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been
>   terminated."

Comment: I guess you are not using parameterized queries which causes sql-injection problems and these kind of problems. Simply put, your input is breaking your sql. Use parameterized queries always http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Was my edit correct? So is the difference between the input that works and the other only the quotes around `"<some text>"`? Show the code where you save it in the db.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes :) by.. *I enter the following text in **codes** * he actually means *I enter the following text in **quotes** *

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the data type of column to **NVarchar**  instead of **Varchar** and save to the database .